# Read online pdf through WebView and swipe Horizontally

Tags: android, webview, mupdf

I am trying to read online pdf through WebView and enabled it to read swipe horizontally. Is it possible ?

Here is my code while read pdf :

```
String doc = "<iframe src='http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://source.android.com/security/reports/Google_Android_Security_2017_Report_Final.pdf&embedded=true' width='100%' height='100%' style='border: none;'></iframe>";
pdfWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
pdfWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
pdfWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
pdfWebView.loadData( doc , "text/html",  "UTF-8");
```

Thanks

Comment: Check my this question. There are lots of libs given to render PDF : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728920/pdf-viewer-api-library-for-android-app

Comment: @VicJordan Most of pdf reader lib is for local file. I already use MuPdf library for reading offline pdf file (stored in local storage). What i need is to read file Pdf through direct link without download it first.

Comment: Why are you messing around with an iframe? Do without. And you did not tell if the html source from google is displayed or not.

Comment: @greenapps iframe is not a matter, because the direct pdf file from URL is still showing with or without iframe. What i want to ask, is it possible if we load direct pdf URL through WebView and read it by swipe horizontally ? just like native reader does.